# Debian buster fix for CVE-2020-29363 issue

Tags: debian

I see  high Vulnerability CVE for Debian buster image, on this page I see fix only for `bullseye, sid` images.

https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2020-29363

Is same fix avialble for buster OS?

Thanks

SR

Answer (score 2):

When the question was posted, the fix wasn’t available for Debian 10. Nor were fixes for [the other vulnerabilities disclosed at the same time](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/p11-kit); they are all classified as “moderate”, not high.

This changed on January 1, 2021, with [DSA-4822](https://www.debian.org/security/2021/dsa-4822). All three CVEs are now addressed in Debian 10; make sure your `p11-kit` packages (`p11-kit`, `p11-kit-modules`, `libp11-kit0` and `libp11-kit-dev`, as appropriate) are upgraded to version 0.23.15-2+deb10u1 or later.

Comment: thank for the info: this one listed as high https://www.tenable.com/cve/CVE-2020-29363. let me see I can reportbug

Comment: Ah, right, I was going by [the assessment in the disclosure](https://github.com/p11-glue/p11-kit/security/advisories/GHSA-5j67-fw89-fp6x).

Comment: my `reportbug` is not working due to firewall setting. unable to file the report.